# Make header in Tumblr theme sticky

Tags: html, css

I am using tumblr to create a blog and am trying to make the header sticky so it stays at the top when you scroll. I have read other posts on here about using position:fixed; in the css but when I do, it messes up the look of the rest of the site. (see screenshot below)

The site is live at: winn-brown.co.uk so if you could have a quick look around that would be much appreciated.

The theme code can be found here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/olleota/themes/master/line/main.html[image: when position:fixed; is put in the css for the site info div]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add following to your current code.

Here problem solved:

```
#masthead {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#content {
    top: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where exactly would i put that in as there seems to be numerous references to #masthead throughout?

Comment: `#masthead` is used only once in your index.html, just copy paste to end of `<style><!-- SOME CODE --><!-- PASTE HERE --></style>` or inside of `*.css` file

Comment: If you look in the code on GitHub I attached you should be able to see that it appears different times in different places. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes It does, but this is not problem. Just copy-paste into `<style>` tag. I suggest you read basics first... http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Could I put it in this bit? #masthead{font-family:'{text:Secondary Google Font name}';position:relative;display:inline-block}

Comment: Yes, you can... Make sure you have backup copy in case anything go wrong.

Comment: I tried it out but it didn't work. Did you look at the html I supplied and try it out?